# Count the number of lines after each pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with lines, some lines have a particular pattern. The number of lines after each pattern differs and I want to count the number of lines after each pattern.

```
<pattern>
line 1
line 2
line 3
<pattern>
line 1
line 2
etc
```

my code:

```
for line in fp:
   c = 0
   if line.startswith("<"):
        header = line.split(" ")
   else:
        c = c+1
```

The code I have captures the pattern as well as the lines, but I don't know how to stop before the next pattern and start another count after the pattern.

Comment: Why not just subtract one from each count?

Comment: patterns are always at the start of line ?

Comment: Yes patterns are always at the start of line

Comment: do you need total sum or lines between each pattern pair ?

Comment: Please restrict yourself to asking about ONE programming language.

Comment: if you need to store dynamically create `List` and add counter for every `<pattern>` block.

Comment: @user3360241 I can get total sum with the above code, I want sum of lines between each pattern pair. Thanks

Comment: How big is your file approximately?

Comment: Hi Laszlo, its 18,530 lines

Comment: Are all the patterns in the file different or there are patterns which can occur more times in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just save the `c` into an array and set `c = 0`

a is the array
l is the length of the array

```
array a;
l = 0;
for line in fp:
 c = 0
 if line.startswith("<"):
    header = line.split(" ")
    a[l] = c
    c = 0
    l = l+1
 else:
    c = c+1
```

To read the values you can read the array from 0 to l:

```
for i in range(0,l):
  print "c%d is %d" % (i,a[i])
```